When is the residue of a compactification connected?
Let $X$ be a topological space, locally compact, hausdorff, and maybe not compact.
Consider a compactification of $X$, $(Y,\varphi)$
What hypothesis would imply that the residue $Y\backslash\varphi(X)$ is connected?

It would rely heavily on the specific compactification procedure, roughly speaking "the collection of different ways to run to infinity". In an extreme example, the residue of the one-point compactification is obviously connected. In a general setting where $Y$ is any compact space with $X$ densely embedded, there isn't a lot to say.

The remainder of any $T_2$-compactification is a continuous image of the remainder of the Stone-Cech compactification. Hence, each remainder is connected, iff the remainder of the Stone-Cech compactification is connected. For instance, this is the case for $[0,1)$, but not for $(0,1)$.

@Ulli Is there any book or article where I can find this result you are talking about? It would help me really much, thanks!

@Camilo Andrés Acevedo Ardila: which one do you exactly asking for?

@Ulli Actually both results you mentioned, the one about the remainder of any T2 compactification, and the iff statement you mentioned.

For the first one see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426726/remainders-of-compactifications-are-images-of-the-stone-%c4%8cech-remainder

The iff-statement then should be clear, since continuous images of connected spaces are connected. Please let me know, what is unclear.

@Ulli : you are right, I don't know why I had this false view in mind : connectedness and path-connectedness are topological properties.

@Ulli thanks, it's clear now, and would there maybe be something that implies that the remainder of the Stone-Cech compactification is connected?

@Camilo Andrés Acevedo Ardila For instance, what I called compactly connected in my answer here. But I think the proof is too involved for a comment.

This should also be detectable in the end compactification (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology))

I think having a unique end should be more or less the same as compactly connected as in @Ulli's last comment

@ronno: "compactly connected" is more general: for instance, spaces having a unique end are $\sigma$-compact, if I understood the Wikipedia definition correctly. For instance, the long line is locally compact, compactly connected, but not $\sigma$-compact, hence has not a unique end.
